# How to use sandbox with google-api-php-client

Tags: php, sandbox, google-api-php-client

I create test orders with https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2.1/orders/createtestorder

How can i get list orders linked to sandbox with https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client ?

I find no way to change v2 in url to v2sandbox

When i test like this i have no returns because i don't call v2sandbox but v2 in url

```
$service = new \Google_Service_ShoppingContent($client);
$orders = $service->orders->listOrders([merchantId]);
```

What i want to call is 
`https://www.googleapis.com/content/v2sandbox/[merchantId]/orders?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`